# Arduino loop stops after for loop in called function

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to make a radio controlled car which reacts to the frequency of music. The Loop works as it should and it gives me the correct frequency. The function `berekenGrootte` works too. This gives me the size of the frequency (max frequency - min frequency). But as soon as I want to use the function `verdeel()` which divides the size of the frequency in 10 to make the car move smoother it does it one or two times and then I don't get any feedback anymore in my serial monitor. Do I use too much `Serial.print` or do I need to restart the loop after the for loop in the second function?

```cpp
#include <FreqMeasure.h>

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(57600);
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
    FreqMeasure.begin();
}

double sum = 0;
int count = 0;
float lowest = 50;
float highest = 0;
float grootte = 50;
float b[9][1];

void loop()
{
    if (FreqMeasure.available()) {
        // average several reading together
        sum = sum + FreqMeasure.read();
        count = count + 1;
        if (count > 30) {
            float frequency = FreqMeasure.countToFrequency(sum / count);
            Serial.println(frequency);
            sum = 0;
            count = 0;
            if (frequency < lowest) {
                lowest = frequency;
                Serial.print("new lowest: ");
                Serial.println(lowest);
                berekenGrootte();
            }
            else if (frequency > highest) {
                highest = frequency;
                Serial.print("new highest: ");
                Serial.println(highest);
                berekenGrootte();
            }
            /*if(frequency > 1000){
                digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
                delay(1000);
                digitalWrite(3,LOW);
            }
            else{
                digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
                delay(1000);
                digitalWrite(5,LOW);
            }*/
        }
    }
}
void berekenGrootte()
{
    grootte = highest - lowest;
    Serial.print("new grootte: ");
    Serial.println(grootte);
    verdeel();
}
void verdeel()
{
    float plength = grootte / 10;
    b[0][0] = lowest;
    b[0][1] = lowest + plength;
    Serial.print("low: ");
    Serial.println(b[0][0]);
    Serial.print("high: ");
    Serial.println(b[0][1]);
    float startvalue = lowest + plength;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        b[i][0] = startvalue;
        b[i][1] = startvalue + plength;
        startvalue = startvalue + plength;
        Serial.print(i);
        Serial.print(" low: ");
        Serial.println(b[i][0]);
        Serial.print(i);
        Serial.print(" high: ");
        Serial.println(b[i][1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overstepping the bounds of your b array.

```
float b[9][1];
```

The array is only 9 * 1.

```
void verdeel()
{
    float plength = grootte / 10;
    b[0][0] = lowest;
    b[0][1] = lowest + plength;
```

So there is no element b[0][1].  The second number can only go up to 0 since the array is size 1 in that dimension.  An array of size 1 is pretty useless as an array.

You have the same problem here in this loop at the end of that function:

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        b[i][0] = startvalue;
        b[i][1] = startvalue + plength;
```

This for loop allows i to go to 9 which is too large for the array.

Comment: Oh I tought it worked like the index  which starts counting from 0. But even with this changed to b[10][2] it stops working.

Comment: I've updated the answer with another example of the same issue in your code.  If it still has problems after fixing that then post the updated code.

Comment: I changed it and removed a bunch of Serial.print commands from my code and it worked. Thank you for your help.